# TypeError: mssql.Schema is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sql-server, react-native

As I'm new to reactJS, someone Please help me to fix the below issue. below code was a reference from a learning tutorial.I have tried a lot to get it fixed, but no luck.

following is the code from User.js file :

```
const mssql = require("mssql");

const UserSchema = new mssql.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        min:3,
        max:50,
        unique:true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 50,
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
      },   
    },
      {timestamps:true}
    );
module.exports=mssql.model("User",Schema);
```

following is the code from Auth.js file :

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");

//REGISTER
router.get("/register", async (req, res)=>{
    const User = await new User({
        username:"****",
        email:"***",
        password:"***"
    })
    User.save();
});

module.exports=router
```

Error I received:

```
const UserSchema = new mssql.Schema({
                   ^

TypeError: mssql.Schema is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vadiv\Desktop\LearnReactJS\models\User.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vadiv\Desktop\LearnReactJS\routes\auth.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Any help here would be greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

```
    const mssql = require("mssql");

const UserSchema = new mssql.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        min:3,
        max:50,
        unique:true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 50,
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
      },   
    },
      {timestamps:true}
    );
module.exports=mssql.model("User",UserSchema );
```

Simple mistake use this code

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I just tried, still getting same issue.. 

Replaced
module.exports=mssql.model("User", Schema); 
by
module.exports=mssql.model("User",UserSchema);

Comment: ok no problem :)